# What kind of Apache access control is recommended when deploying a Django site

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I've looked at a number of tutorials, some recommending multiple [access controls](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html) and some none.

For example, one I've come across is:

```
<Directory /var/www/myproject>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

That's the only control I have specified right now.

I'm revisiting these contorls because one of my Django URLs is returning an HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed.

What directories should be controlled?

Comment: Since your site works and the 405 is only happening on one URL, it can't possibly be the fault of the Apache configuration.

Answer (score 0):

If your Django project serves static and/or media files then you have to allow access to those directories too. [**See here**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/) for further details.

```
##Sample httpd.conf
<VirtualHost 1xx.xx.x.x:80>

ServerName 1xx.xx.x.x

AliasMatch ^/([^/]*\.css) /path/to/your/project/static/styles/$1

Alias /media/ /path/to/your/project/media/
Alias /static/ /path/to/your/project/static/

<Directory /path/to/your/project/static>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory /path/to/your/project/media>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/your/project/apache/wsgi.py

<Directory /path/to/your/project/apache>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: So I only need to specify my static folder? I don't have a media folder.

Comment: Yes just the path to your static folder